# Energy conservation and magnetic field around wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

A current-carrying wire has a magnetic field around it according to the Maxwell equations (Oersted's law/Biot–Savart law). When this is AC current, then also the magnetic field oscillates. The energy density in the magnetic field is given by
$$U(t)=\mu_0\frac{H(t)^2}{2} = \mu_0\frac{\tilde{H}}{2}e^{i2\omega t}\,.$$

Power is defined as the time derivative of energy and thus becomes
$$P(t) = \frac{U(t)}{dt} = \mu_0i\omega \tilde{H} e^{i2\omega t}\,.$$

What is the physical interpretation of this oscillating energy and power? If the energy in the magnetic field decreases, then it has to go somewhere else because of the conservation of energy? It looks like there are two systems that are in resonance with each other, but which is the second system?

Comment: Your formula with $2i\omega t$ is incorrect. You can't plug in phasor representation into energy formulae. You have to use real magnetic field induction $B = B_0\sin \omega t$ then energy density is $\frac{B^2}{2\mu_0}$.

Comment: The real part of the energy is the active energy and the imaginary part is reactive energy?

Comment: No. Real part of your expression is $\tilde{H}/2 \cos 2\omega t$. This has zero time average value. Energy density of oscillating magnetic field does not have zero time average.

Answer (score -1):

For the *Poynting Theorem* in SI units
\begin{gather*}
\nabla\cdot
\boldsymbol{S}
+\frac{\partial\mathscr{U}^{\text{em}}}{\partial t}
+\boldsymbol{j}\cdot\boldsymbol{E}
=
0
\\
\boldsymbol{S}
\doteq
\mu^{-1}
\boldsymbol{E}
\times
\boldsymbol{B}
\end{gather*}
where the electromagnetic field associated with the motion of *a single* charge is given by the Liénard-Wiechert theory of retarded potential
\begin{gather*}
\boldsymbol{E}_i(\boldsymbol{r},t)=
\frac{q_i\left(1-\boldsymbol{\beta}_i^2\right)}{4\pi\varepsilon |\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_i|^2\kappa_i^3}(\boldsymbol{n}_i-\boldsymbol{\beta}_i)
+
\frac{q_i}{4\pi\varepsilon c |\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_i|\kappa_i^3}
\,\boldsymbol{n}_i\times\left(
\left(\boldsymbol{n}_i-\boldsymbol{\beta}_i\right)\times
\dot{\boldsymbol{\beta}_i}\right)
\\
\boldsymbol{B}_i(\boldsymbol{r},t)
=
c^{-1}\boldsymbol{n}_i\times\boldsymbol{E}_i
=
-\frac{q_i\left(1-\boldsymbol{\beta}_i^2\right)}{4\pi\varepsilon c |\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_i|^2\kappa_i^3}\boldsymbol{n}_i\times\boldsymbol{\beta}_i
+
\frac{q_i}{4\pi\varepsilon c^2 |\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_i|\kappa_i^3}
\boldsymbol{n}_i\times\dot{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_i
\end{gather*}
The point is just that the part of the electromagnetic field, dependent on the acceleration of the particle (in the AC current every single charge oscillates), is called also the *acceleration field* and fundamentally represents photon emission.
By looking at the definition of the *Poynting vector* $\boldsymbol{S}$ and the Poynting theorem you get the reason why your system is loosing energy; it's emitting.

Edit:

To be clearer, unifying the presented results in the non relativistic case, you obtain the *Larmor Formula*
\begin{equation*}
P_i
=
-\frac{\mu q_i^2}{6\pi c}
|\ddot{\boldsymbol{r}}_i|^2
\end{equation*}
Note that an armonic motion with $\omega$ frequency gives a power loss with $2\omega$ oscillation frequency.

In the case of a system of particle you can use the *dipole approximation*
\begin{equation*}
P
=
-\frac{\mu}{6\pi c}
|\ddot{\boldsymbol{d}}|^2
\end{equation*}
where $\ddot{\boldsymbol{d}}$ is the net dipole moment of the system.
Fundamentally what you have with an ac current in a cable is an antenna.